# Is this true - we need ordered JSON?

Tags: json, wcf, webserver, deserialization

I was trying to send following JSON Body

```
{
    "ID": "3d7effda-8e3a-4254-bc4a-32c473ce473f",
    "Projects": [
        {
            "__type": "ProductEvaluationReference:#abc.Think.Projects",
            "ID": "01ff01cb-d3a5-4a36-b274-446cdcbd93a2",
            "Type": "ProductEvaluation"
        },
        {
            "__type": "FinancialAssessmentReference:#abc.Think.Projects",
            "ID": "403030bf-dc7d-4e4f-ae5b-b25c6b61e986",
            "Type": "FinancialAssessment"
        },
        {
            "__type": "ProductSurveyReference:#abc.Think.Projects",
            "ID": "8e43e41f-d200-4508-9c48-f0ee6e8baf99",
            "Type": "ProductSurvey"
        },
        {
            "__type": "ProductSurveyReference:#abc.Think.Projects",
            "ID": "e066c8ae-e268-4e9d-b2b0-ecb888d9a238",
            "Type": "ProductSurvey"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

This works perfectly. But if I change the ordering of `__type` field in the request i.e instead of first key in the dictionary and make it the second key. I get an error `Cannot create abstract class`. For Example:

```
{
    "ID": "403030bf-dc7d-4e4f-ae5b-  b25c6b61e986",
    "_type": "FinancialAssessmentReference:#abc.Think.Projects",
    "Type": "FinancialAssessment"
}
```

I read the following on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)

> Type Hint Position in JSON Objects
>   Note that the type hint must appear first in the JSON representation. This is the only case where order of key/value pairs
>   is important in JSON processing.

Is this really true that we need `ORDERED JSON` or do I have some thing wrong on the server side. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that we needed an ordered JSON. I created a subclass of NSDictionary the add some ordering to keys.

Comment: Please give more detail about your solution.